# Cartopy does not draw coastlines when I change projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot the coastlines in the north part of the Mediterranean Sea.

The following script, that uses PlateCarre projection, works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from sys import exit as sys_exit


def main():
    plt.figure(dpi=600)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2 = 12., 16., 43.3, 46.
    ax.set_extent([lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines()

    plt.savefig('test.pdf')
    plt.close()

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys_exit(main())
```

If I replace ccrs.PlateCarree with ccrs.Mercator, instead, I get an empty image.
Here is the script with the replaced projection:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from sys import exit as sys_exit


def main():
    plt.figure(dpi=600)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())

    lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2 = 12., 16., 43.3, 46.
    ax.set_extent([lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2], crs=ccrs.Mercator())
    ax.coastlines()

    plt.savefig('test.pdf')
    plt.close()

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys_exit(main())
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mercator coordinate system does not use degrees.  If you still want to specify the extent in degrees you can use the `PlateCarree` crs for that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())

lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2 = 12., 16., 43.3, 46.
ax.set_extent([lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But now I am even more confused: when do I have to use Mercator and when do I have to use PlateCarree? For example, if I draw a scatter plot, the argument of "transform" must be PlateCarree or Mercator? Do you know if the official documentation explains this?

Comment: Hopefully this page will help https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html